# Find the candidate with the most number of skills

Tags: node.js, api, crud

I am creating a REST API with Data Structures. Given this kind of Data Structure:-

```
   {
       "id": 1'
       "name": "Clint",
       "skills": ["javascript", "java", nodejs"]
    },
   {
       "id": 1'
       "name": "Clint",
       "skills": ["javascript", "java", nodejs"]
    }
```

How can I get the candidate with the most number of skills?

Comment: What about writing some code to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
    const candidates = [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Clint",
        "skills": ["javascript", "java", "nodejs"]
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Clint2",
        "skills": ["javascript", "java", "nodejs", "orm"]
      }];

    // sort it by skills.length
    const sortedCandidtes = candidates.sort((a,b)=>b.skills.length-a.skills.length)

    const mostSkilled = sortedCandidtes[0];
```